# How do I sum up the value of a column if there id is same using python

Tags: python, excel

I have  to take difference of time of the two columns in excel only when the id is same in the below column or else skip

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPiCV.jpg]

eg :id=119 is same in the next column so take the difference of there time and save it in another column.

can it be done using pandas or any other way.

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved by the formula:

=if(A1=A2, B2-B1) i.e, A is the column containing ids and B is the column containing time

It can be solved in Python as follows

```
#  import Workbook
    from openpyxl import Workbook
# create Workbook object
    wb=Workbook()
# set file path
    filepath="/home/ubuntu/demo.xlsx"
# select demo.xlsx
    sheet =wb.active
#set row count
    max_row=sheet.max_row
    for i in range(1,max_row) 
        if (A[i] ==A[i+1]):
            Second=sheet.cell(row=i+1,column=2)
            First =sheet.cell(row=i,column=2)
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=3').value= Second-First
# save file
    wb.save(filepath)
```

Comment: This can be solved by the formula:

=if(A1=A2, B2-B1) i.e, A is the column containing ids and B is the column containing time

It can be solved in Python as follows

# import Workbook
    from openpyxl import Workbook
# create Workbook object
    wb=Workbook()
# set file path
    filepath="/home/ubuntu/demo.xlsx"
# select demo.xlsx
    sheet =wb.active
#set row count
    max_row=sheet.max_row
    for i in range(1,max_row) 
        if (A[i] ==A[i+1]):
            Second=sheet.cell(row=i+1,column=2)
            First =sheet.cell(row=i,column=2)
            sheet.cell(row=i, column=3').value= Sec